# UICollectionview with uidynamics reload data issue

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewlayout

I have been working on an app that uses `UIDynamics` in `UICollectionView`. I have watched Apple WWDC video and have also tried [this sample app in Github](https://github.com/arik-so/UIDynamics-CollectionView).

However, I had this weird problem: When my app launches, I set the number of items for my collection view to 0, the app needs to download something from the server then populate the collection view on the main thread. Weirdly, it's (kinda) reloaded, but not showing anything. I tried on the sample app from Github and it has the same issue as well.

However, if I remove this part:

```
- (NSArray *)layoutAttributesForElementsInRect:(CGRect)rect{
    return [self.dynamicAnimator itemsInRect:rect];
}
```

The `CollectionView` will show what I want but without the `UIDynamics`.

I hope the illustration on my problem is easy to understand. Any help will be much appreciated. My guess is I shouldn't use reloaddata.